# excel vba Summing Line Items in Rows

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a link to an Excel .xlsm file that has the code in the module: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlZlJzS0VTZXNORlU/view?usp=sharing

The problem lies in how the result is getting presented. For example, for a particular WR# the result should be 2.104 but the calculated result is not.

Here is a test result doc: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlOVk5Zk13VXdQUlE/view?usp=sharing

The purpose of this calculation is to get line entry for each WR# and then use the formula to sum up the value for a particular WR# but the resulting calculation not doing this. Hoping to get any help.

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeanRobertReport()

' The following code renames the Active sheet to AccessImport

'ActiveSheet.Name = "AccessImport"

' Activate a sheet
Worksheets("AccessImport").Activate

    ' Get the start and end date from the user

    Dim TheString1 As String, TheString2 As String, TheStartDate As Date, TheEndDate As Date
    Dim TotalDaysEntered As Integer



    TheString1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the start date:")

    If IsDate(TheString1) Then
        TheStartDate = DateValue(TheString1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid date entered"
    End If


    TheString2 = Application.InputBox("Enter the end date:")

    If IsDate(TheString2) Then
        TheEndDate = DateValue(TheString2)
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid date entered"
    End If

 '   TotalDaysEntered = (TheEndDate - TheStartDate) + 1

 ' The following code extracts the data for a specific date range provided by the user.

     ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_ARM_Activity_Tracker").Range.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & TheStartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & TheEndDate


' The next block of code fills up all the blank cells found in column A with E4486 or 004486.

    Dim c As Integer

    For c = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("A" & c).Value = vbNullString Then
            Range("A" & c).Value = "004486"
        End If
    Next c

    Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter


Dim LastRowFrom As Long
Dim LastRowTo As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim temp As Long
Dim found As Boolean
    'determines the last row that contains data in column A
LastRowFrom = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


' Copy data from active sheet to another sheet

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "DeanRoberts"
Worksheets("AccessImport").Activate

Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook
mainworkBook.Sheets("AccessImport").UsedRange.Copy

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Select

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Range("A1").Select

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Paste


' Find the unique values and place these identified unique values from Column         A into Column J

Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Activate

Dim d2 As Object, c2 As Variant, i2 As Long, lr2 As Long
Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c2 = Range("A2:A" & lr2)
For i2 = 1 To UBound(c2, 1)
  d2(c2(i2, 1)) = 1
Next i2
Range("J2").Resize(d2.Count) = Application.Transpose(d2.keys)



' Clear contents after the last rows with values in column J

Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Activate


' Sum values found in column B for each unique WR# in Column J, output the result on Column K, L, M, N

Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim calcFormula1 As Double
Dim calcFormula2 As Double
Dim calcFormula3 As Double
Dim calcFormula4 As Double
Dim calcFormula10 As Double
Dim calcFormula20 As Double
Dim calcFormula30 As Double
Dim calcFormula40 As Double

For rowIndex = 2 To lr2

    calcFormula10 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("B:B")))
    calcFormula20 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("C:C")))
    calcFormula30 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("D:D")))
    calcFormula40 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("E:E")))

    If (calcFormula10 = 0) Then
        calcFormula1 = 0
    Else
'        calcFormula1 = calcFormula10 + 0.08
        calcFormula1 = calcFormula10
    End If


    If (calcFormula20 = 0) Then
        calcFormula2 = 0
    Else
'        calcFormula2 = calcFormula20 + 0.08
         calcFormula2 = calcFormula20
    End If


    If (calcFormula30 = 0) Then
        calcFormula3 = 0
    Else
'        calcFormula3 = calcFormula30 + 0.08
        calcFormula3 = calcFormula30
    End If


    If (calcFormula40 = 0) Then
        calcFormula4 = 0
    Else
'        calcFormula4 = calcFormula40 + 0.08
        calcFormula4 = calcFormula40
    End If


    Cells(rowIndex, "K").Value = calcFormula1
    Cells(rowIndex, "L").Value = calcFormula2
    Cells(rowIndex, "M").Value = calcFormula3
    Cells(rowIndex, "N").Value = calcFormula4




'    Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = ((Cells(rowIndex, "K").Value + Cells(rowIndex, "L").Value + Cells(rowIndex, "M").Value + Cells(rowIndex, "N").Value))
    Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = calcFormula1 + calcFormula2 + calcFormula3 + calcFormula4 + 0.08


Next rowIndex


' Sort values, lowest to highest number WR#

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DeanRoberts")
    With .Cells(2, 10).CurrentRegion
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End With


Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("O1").Select
Columns("O:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Inserting title of the columns

Cells(1, "J").Value = "WR#"
Cells(1, "K").Value = "Prints"
Cells(1, "L").Value = "Plots"
Cells(1, "M").Value = "Laminate"
Cells(1, "N").Value = "Scans"
Cells(1, "O").Value = "Total Usage"


Cells(1, 10).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 11).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 12).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 13).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 14).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 15).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 16).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 17).Font.Bold = True
Cells(1, 18).Font.Bold = True

Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

' Hide multiple column ranges

Columns("A:I").Hidden = True
'Columns("K:N").Hidden = True

Dim WS4 As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

' Delete empty cells based on values on J column

Set WS4 = Worksheets("DeanRoberts")

With WS4
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
    Rows(LastCellRowNumber + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
End With

'End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code here?

Comment: Just posted the code Bruce.

Comment: I'll try to take a look.  Do you know where in the code your issue is occurring?  Is it during the `calcFormula10 = (Application...` part?

Comment: Yes, I believe the problem is inside the for loop section of the code. I have tried variation of the calculation inside the loop but could not get the expected value in the result.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a small bit of sample data, so I can try to run this on my comp? Or if I just use random numbers between say 10 and 1000, will that work too (or are you using decimals, etc.)?

Comment: Hi Bruce, the link to the .xlsm file that has the data and the code is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlZlJzS0VTZXNORlU/view?usp=sharing  The test result can be found at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlOVk5Zk13VXdQUlE/view?usp=sharing   Let me know if you have any access problem with these files. When you run the code for the first time, it will generate a worksheet it just needs to be deleted except the the sheet titled "AccessImport" before the code can run the second time.

Comment: I worked through it, and I think it's just an issue with your formula.  Can you walk through more detailed what you intend to do with the calculation? Which calculation is not correct? I see you're adding the number of Prints, Plots, Lamanation ft., and Scans, for each WR#.  Which formula is not giving the correct answer?  Can you explain which row, and how, it should be 2.104?

Comment: Hi Bruce, I have uploaded a new test file with step by step description along with screenshots. Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlbjZ5VktSTlFRMEE/view?usp=sharing    Here is the Excel file with data and the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlbVc4S2Zkc3M2RnM/view?usp=sharing   Let me know if there is any access issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll look through.  Quick note: I think there's a typo (missed math operator) in your `Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = calcFormula1 + calcFormula2 + calcFormula3 + calcFormula4 ...` line.  You didn't include the multiplying of .008, try replacing that with `Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = (calcFormula1 + calcFormula2 + calcFormula3 + calcFormula4) * 0.008 + 0.08`

Comment: Hi Bruce, The multiplication (*0.008) was done when calcFormula10, 20, 30 and 40 were calculated: these are the first 4 lines of codes (not commented out) after the For loop begins. I have played variations of these, like multiplying and adding in "O", but didn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in A1, here's the fake data I used:

```
WR# Prints  Plots   Lamanatin sqft  Scans   Dept ID Date    Empl
32313   0   8   0   0   PCD 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
35459   1   5   1   1   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
33133   2   6   2   0   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
29985   10  6   3   0   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
22762   5   9   4   2   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
30927   11  1   5   0   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
27530   14  7   6   0   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
35444   9   8   7   3   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
23978   13  2   8   3   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
34645   14  2   9   1   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
29299   1   8   10  0   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
27612   5   3   11  0   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
24938   5   3   12  1   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
26142   1   2   13  2   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
30093   2   5   14  0   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
35578   15  7   15  1   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
32651   8   0   16  2   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
33602   2   5   17  2   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
29629   11  0   18  2   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
29687   2   1   19  2   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
20179   0   1   20  1   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
28558   15  4   21  3   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
33554   13  5   22  1   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
30363   12  7   23  3   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
29145   1   1   24  1   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
35480   11  1   25  1   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
25047   8   7   26  1   Net 6/24/2015   Dean Robert
```

And here's a sub:

```
Sub DeanRobertReport()

' The following code renames the Active sheet to AccessImport

'ActiveSheet.Name = "AccessImport"

' Activate a sheet
Worksheets("AccessImport").Activate

' Get the start and end date from the user

Dim TheString1 As String, TheString2 As String, TheStartDate As Date, TheEndDate As Date
Dim TotalDaysEntered As Integer

Do While Not IsDate(TheString1)    'This will loop until you correctly give a start date
    TheString1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the start date:")
Loop

Do While Not IsDate(TheString2)
    TheString2 = Application.InputBox("Enter the end date:")
Loop

' The following code extracts the data for a specific date range provided by the user.

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_ARM_Activity_Tracker").Range.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & TheStartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & TheEndDate
Debug.Print "HI"
' The next block of code fills up all the blank cells found in column A with E4486 or 004486.

Dim c       As Integer

For c = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("A" & c).Value = vbNullString Then
        Range("A" & c).Value = "004486"
    End If
Next c

Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter


Dim LastRowFrom As Long
Dim LastRowTo As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim temp    As Long
Dim found   As Boolean
'determines the last row that contains data in column A
LastRowFrom = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


' Copy data from active sheet to another sheet

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.name = "DeanRoberts"
Worksheets("AccessImport").Activate

Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook
mainworkBook.Sheets("AccessImport").UsedRange.Copy

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Select
mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Range("A1").Select

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Paste


' Find the unique values and place these identified unique values from Column         A into Column J

Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Activate

Dim d2 As Object, c2 As Variant, i2 As Long, lr2 As Long
Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c2 = Range("A2:A" & lr2)
For i2 = 1 To UBound(c2, 1)
    d2(c2(i2, 1)) = 1
Next i2
Range("J2").Resize(d2.Count) = Application.Transpose(d2.keys)

' Clear contents after the last rows with values in column J

Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Activate

' Sum values found in column B for each unique WR# in Column J, output the result on Column K, L, M, N

Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim calcFormula1 As Double
Dim calcFormula2 As Double
Dim calcFormula3 As Double
Dim calcFormula4 As Double
Dim calcFormula10 As Double
Dim calcFormula20 As Double
Dim calcFormula30 As Double
Dim calcFormula40 As Double

For rowIndex = 2 To lr2

    calcFormula10 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("B:B")))
    calcFormula20 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("C:C")))
    calcFormula30 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("D:D")))
    calcFormula40 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("E:E")))

    'Check the values
    Debug.Print "calcFormula10: " & calcFormula10
    Debug.Print "calcFormula20: " & calcFormula20
    Debug.Print "calcFormula30: " & calcFormula30
    Debug.Print "calcFormula40: " & calcFormula40


    If (calcFormula10 = 0) Then
        calcFormula1 = 0
    Else
        '        calcFormula1 = calcFormula10 + 0.08
        calcFormula1 = calcFormula10
    End If


    If (calcFormula20 = 0) Then
        calcFormula2 = 0
    Else
        '        calcFormula2 = calcFormula20 + 0.08
        calcFormula2 = calcFormula20
    End If


    If (calcFormula30 = 0) Then
        calcFormula3 = 0
    Else
        '        calcFormula3 = calcFormula30 + 0.08
        calcFormula3 = calcFormula30
    End If


    If (calcFormula40 = 0) Then
        calcFormula4 = 0
    Else
        '        calcFormula4 = calcFormula40 + 0.08
        calcFormula4 = calcFormula40
    End If

    Cells(rowIndex, "K").Value = calcFormula1
    Cells(rowIndex, "L").Value = calcFormula2
    Cells(rowIndex, "M").Value = calcFormula3
    Cells(rowIndex, "N").Value = calcFormula4

    '    Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = ((Cells(rowIndex, "K").Value + Cells(rowIndex, "L").Value + Cells(rowIndex, "M").Value + Cells(rowIndex, "N").Value))
    Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = (calcFormula1 + calcFormula2 + calcFormula3 + calcFormula4) * 0.008 + 0.08

Next rowIndex


' Sort values, lowest to highest number WR#

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DeanRoberts")
    With .Cells(2, 10).CurrentRegion
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End With


Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("O1").Select
Columns("O:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Inserting title of the columns


Cells(1, "J").Value = "WR#"
Cells(1, "K").Value = "Prints"
Cells(1, "L").Value = "Plots"
Cells(1, "M").Value = "Laminate"
Cells(1, "N").Value = "Scans"
Cells(1, "O").Value = "Total Usage"

For i = 10 To 18             'This will shorten your BOLD code a bit
    Cells(1, i).Font.Bold = True
Next i

Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

' Hide multiple column ranges

Columns("A:I").Hidden = True
'Columns("K:N").Hidden = True

Dim WS4     As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

' Delete empty cells based on values on J column

Set WS4 = Worksheets("DeanRoberts")

With WS4
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
    Rows(LastCellRowNumber + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
End With

'End With

End Sub
```

How close/far is that from what you're looking for?

Edit: 
Updated code to not SUM similar WR#s:

```
Sub DeanRobertReport()

' The following code renames the Active sheet to AccessImport

'ActiveSheet.Name = "AccessImport"

' Activate a sheet
Worksheets("AccessImport").Activate

' Get the start and end date from the user

Dim TheString1 As String, TheString2 As String, TheStartDate As Date, TheEndDate As Date
Dim TotalDaysEntered As Integer

Do While Not IsDate(TheString1)    'This will loop until you correctly give a start date
    TheString1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the start date:")
Loop

Do While Not IsDate(TheString2)
    TheString2 = Application.InputBox("Enter the end date:")
Loop

' The following code extracts the data for a specific date range provided by the user.

' ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_ARM_Activity_Tracker").Range.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & TheStartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & TheEndDate
Debug.Print "HI"
' The next block of code fills up all the blank cells found in column A with E4486 or 004486.

Dim c       As Integer

For c = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("A" & c).Value = vbNullString Then
        Range("A" & c).Value = "004486"
    End If
Next c

Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter


Dim LastRowFrom As Long
Dim LastRowTo As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim temp    As Long
Dim found   As Boolean
'determines the last row that contains data in column A
LastRowFrom = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


' Copy data from active sheet to another sheet

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.name = "DeanRoberts"
Worksheets("AccessImport").Activate

Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook
mainworkBook.Sheets("AccessImport").UsedRange.Copy

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Select
mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Range("A1").Select

mainworkBook.Sheets("DeanRoberts").Paste


' Find the unique values and place these identified unique values from Column         A into Column J

Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Activate

Dim d2 As Object, c2 As Variant, i2 As Long, lr2 As Long
Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lr2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c2 = Range("A2:A" & lr2)
For i2 = 1 To UBound(c2, 1)
    d2(c2(i2, 1)) = 1
Next i2
Range("J2").Resize(d2.Count) = Application.Transpose(d2.keys)

' Clear contents after the last rows with values in column J

Worksheets("DeanRoberts").Activate

' Sum values found in column B for each unique WR# in Column J, output the result on Column K, L, M, N

Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim calcFormula1 As Double
Dim calcFormula2 As Double
Dim calcFormula3 As Double
Dim calcFormula4 As Double
Dim calcFormula10 As Double
Dim calcFormula20 As Double
Dim calcFormula30 As Double
Dim calcFormula40 As Double

For rowIndex = 2 To lr2

    calcFormula10 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("B:B")))
    calcFormula20 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("C:C")))
    calcFormula30 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("D:D")))
    calcFormula40 = (Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(rowIndex, "J").Text, Range("E:E")))

    'Check the values
    Debug.Print "calcFormula10: " & calcFormula10
    Debug.Print "calcFormula20: " & calcFormula20
    Debug.Print "calcFormula30: " & calcFormula30
    Debug.Print "calcFormula40: " & calcFormula40


    If (calcFormula10 = 0) Then
        calcFormula1 = 0
    Else
        '        calcFormula1 = calcFormula10 + 0.08
        calcFormula1 = calcFormula10
    End If


    If (calcFormula20 = 0) Then
        calcFormula2 = 0
    Else
        '        calcFormula2 = calcFormula20 + 0.08
        calcFormula2 = calcFormula20
    End If


    If (calcFormula30 = 0) Then
        calcFormula3 = 0
    Else
        '        calcFormula3 = calcFormula30 + 0.08
        calcFormula3 = calcFormula30
    End If


    If (calcFormula40 = 0) Then
        calcFormula4 = 0
    Else
        '        calcFormula4 = calcFormula40 + 0.08
        calcFormula4 = calcFormula40
    End If

'    Cells(rowIndex, "K").Value = calcFormula1
'    Cells(rowIndex, "L").Value = calcFormula2
'    Cells(rowIndex, "M").Value = calcFormula3
'    Cells(rowIndex, "N").Value = calcFormula4

For i = 11 To 14
    Cells(rowIndex, i).Value = Cells(rowIndex, i).Offset(0, -9).Value
Next i
    '    Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = ((Cells(rowIndex, "K").Value + Cells(rowIndex, "L").Value + Cells(rowIndex, "M").Value + Cells(rowIndex, "N").Value))
    'Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = (calcFormula1 + calcFormula2 + calcFormula3 + calcFormula4) * 0.008 + 0.08
    Cells(rowIndex, "O").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(rowIndex, 11), Cells(rowIndex, 14))) * 0.008 + 0.08
Next rowIndex


' Sort values, lowest to highest number WR#

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DeanRoberts")
    With .Cells(2, 10).CurrentRegion
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End With


Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("O1").Select
Columns("O:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Inserting title of the columns


Cells(1, "J").Value = "WR#"
Cells(1, "K").Value = "Prints"
Cells(1, "L").Value = "Plots"
Cells(1, "M").Value = "Laminate"
Cells(1, "N").Value = "Scans"
Cells(1, "O").Value = "Total Usage"

'This will shorten your BOLD code a bit
    Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(1, 18)).Font.Bold = True


Columns("A:W").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

' Hide multiple column ranges

Columns("A:I").Hidden = True
'Columns("K:N").Hidden = True

Dim WS4     As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

' Delete empty cells based on values on J column

Set WS4 = Worksheets("DeanRoberts")

With WS4
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
    Rows(LastCellRowNumber + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
End With

'End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Bruce. I will check and respond later this afternoon. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have run the code. This works for single WR# entries, but when multiple WR# have the same number, it is not calculating it correctly. For example, for WR# 35459, I have inserted a row, so the values in first row is: (35459, 2, 4, 7, 1, Net, 6/24/2015, Dean Robert), the second row has (35459, 1, 5, 1, 1, Net, 6/24/2015, Dean Robert). The expected result from first row should be: (2+4+7+1)*0.008+0.08 = 0.192 and the second row should be: (1+5+1+1)*0.008+0.08 = 0.144. Total = 0.192+0.144 = 0.336. But the code is showing the result as 0.256, resulting from ((2+1)+(4+5)+(7+1)+(1+1))*0.008 + 0.08.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll check it out.  Quick clarification, what's your `ListObject` `"Table_ARM_Activity_Tracker"`?

Comment: The reason it was adding the two 3549 entries, as you explained, is because you're using Sumif to do the adding.  It's therefore looking in Column A for any 3459, and adding the values.  Do you *need* sumif? Or can we do Sum, if you don't need the WR#s combined?

Comment: Hi Bruce, "Table_ARM_Activity_Tracker" is the name of the Access file that the data was obtained from. I had deleted any unnecessary code from the sample.

Comment: I updated the code - how's it looking now?  Also, can you explain why you're using the `calcFormula1`, `calcFormula2`, etc? I see that if the `calcFormula10` is 0, then set `calcFormula1` to 0, otherwise set it to whatever `calcFormula10` is ...why not just skip using the second variable and just use `calcFormula10`?

Comment: Hi Bruce, it calculated the first entry for WR# 35459 = 0.192. Please note that I had inserted an extra row for WR# 35459 to test the multiple entry calculation for the same WR#. For the single entry, it works (#35459 = 0.192), but for the multiple entry, the calculation not counting the second entry (should be for #35459 = 0.336. Here is the link to the updated file using the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLiHD7QMfVlYlRzdnp2dlF0cUE/view?usp=sharing